# Populate value of a property of a column in another column

Tags: rdf, openrefine

```
Column 1             Column 2
```

Column1 -> foaf:name -> Column 2

Lets say I want to display the name of the person pointed to by the Column 1 URI in the Column 2. Is there a way to accomplish this with openrefine and rdf extension?

Answer (score 0):

If the URI is dereferenceable, you could do it using "Add column by fetching URL" with your subject URI and then parsing the resulting data.  Don't know if there's a simpler way using the RDF extension.

This issue is probably relevant: https://github.com/fadmaa/grefine-rdf-extension/issues/43